# Contar elementos de una tabla según valores de un atributo

Tags: base-de-datos, sql

Quiero aprender una manera más fácil de hacer una consulta donde mando a contar los resultados de cierto código.

Está es la sentencia que realizo para obtener el contador de todos los individuos que tienen sexo = 'M':

```
select count(codigo) as contM, from cliente where sexo='M' and agencia='01'
```

pero tengo otros códigos de sexo (F y L) que de igual manera quisiera consultar en la misma sentencia; yo realizo varias consultas que también me dan el mismo resultado, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de consultar 3 veces la misma columna pero cada condicional relacionada al sexo es diferente.

Comment: Me parece que buscas agrupar y contar en la misma sentencia: `select distinct codigo, count(codigo)as contM, from cliente where agencia='01' group by codigo`. Aunque no especificaste para qué gestor de base de datos...

Comment: Hola, hay 2 formas, una en 3 filas como te indicaron y otra en 3 columnas, depende cual buscas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes mostrarla en 3 filas:

```
select sexo, count(codigo) as cont 
from cliente 
where agencia='01' 
group by sexo
```

el resultado se vería de la siguiente forma:

```
sexo |cont
------------
M    |25
F    |27
L    |4
```

ó en 3 columnas:

```
select sum(if(sexo='M',1,0)) as contM,
sum(if(sexo='F',1,0)) as contF,
sum(if(sexo='L',1,0)) as contL
from cliente
where agencia='01'
```

el resultado se vería de la siguiente forma:

```
contM|contF|contL
--------------------
25   |27   |4
```

En ambos casos se usan funciones de agregación y para el primer caso `group by`.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.